# when does a sequence of bounded diffusions converge

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ a probability space with filtration generated by brownian motion $W(t),0\leq t\leq T$
I have a sequence $\eta^n(s)$ of diffusions $s\mapsto \eta^n(s)$ is continuous
I know that

$0\leq \eta^n(s)\leq 1$

and we also know that $d\eta^n(s)=a_n(s,\eta^n(s))ds+b_n(s,\eta^n(s))dW(s)$

where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded lipschitz continuous

$|\eta^{n+1}(s)-\eta^n(s)|\leq \frac{C^n}{n!}\exp(2W_s)$

Does $\eta^n(s)$ converge almost surely ?
If the limit is $\eta(s)$

and $a_n$ , $b_n$ converge to $a, b$.

When can we say $d\eta(s)=a(s,\eta(s))ds+b(s,\eta(s))dW_s$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $X=\max_{t\in[0,T]}|W_t|$. Then $|\eta^{n+1}(s)-\eta^n(s)|\le\frac{C^n}{n!}\exp(2X)$ almost surely. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{C^n}{n!}\exp(2X)=\exp(2X+C)<\infty$, it follows from the Weierstrass M-test that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\eta^{n+1}(s)-\eta^n(s))$$
converges absolutely and uniformly in $s$. Noting that $\eta^n(s)=\eta^0(s)+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\eta^{j+1}(s)-\eta^j(s))$, it follows that $\eta^n\to\eta:=\eta^0+\sum_{j=0}^\infty(\eta^{j+1}-\eta^j)$ uniformly in $s$ almost surely. Since $s\mapsto\eta^n(s)$ is continuous and the convergence is uniform, $\eta$ is also continuous.